# $A$ subset $B$ implies $f(A)$ subset $f(B)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

prove: let $f:X\rightarrow Y$. Then for any subset $A$ and $B$ of $X$,

a) $$f(A\cap B) \subset f(A)\cap f(B)$$
b) $$A\subset B \Rightarrow f(A)\subset f(B)$$

proof of a):

Let $y\in f(A\cap B)$, then there is an $x\in A\cap B$ so that $$f(x) = y$$ But $x\in A$ so $f(x)\in f(A)$ and $x\in B$ so $f(x)\in f(B)$. Therefore, $$f(x)\in f(A)\cap f(B) \ \   i.e. \  y\in f(A)\cap f(B) $$

proof of b):

Take an arbitrary element $x\in f(A)$, then there exists a $y\in A$ so that $$f(y) = x$$

Now, take an arbitrary element $x\in f(B)$, then there exists a $y\in B$ so that $$f(y)= x$$

So, for every $y\in A$ and $y\in B$, $f(y)\in f(A)$ and $f(y)\in f(B)$ also for any $x\in f(A)$, $x\in f(B)$. Therefore, $f(A)\subset f(B)$

Are my proofs correct? If not, can you provide reasoning and if the proof is not complete please show me what I need to further add

Comment: And you question is?

Comment: sorry let me edit it

Comment: just curious, is there a name for this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) looks good. However, that b) part is a bit confusing. You were doing fine until you took an $x\in f(B)$. That was unnecessary, and also ambiguous, as you now have two different $x$'s and $y$'s, and no way of telling which is which.

Take an $x \in f(A)$. Then there is an $y\in A$ such that $f(y) = x$. Now, we also have $y\in B$, since $A\subset B$. Therefore $f(y) \in f(B)$, which means $x \in f(B)$.

Comment: By the way, (a) is a consequence of (b).