# Given a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ where $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$, prove that $A\subset B \Rightarrow f(A)\subset f(B)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I know this question has already been posted here [$A$
subset $$ implies $f(A)$ subset $f()$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183793/a-subset-b-implies-fa-subset-fb). However, I would like to know if my approach is just as fine.

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a mapping from $X$ into $Y$. Show that if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$, then

$$(A\subset B)\Rightarrow (f(A)\subset f(B))$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Indeed, due to the hypothesis, which is equivalent to $A\cap B = A$, one has
\begin{align*}
f(A) & = \{y\in Y \mid\exists x\,(x\in A)\wedge(y = f(x))\} = \{y\in Y \mid\exists x\,(x\in A\cap B)\wedge(y = f(x))\} \\\\
& = \{y\in Y \mid\exists x\,(x\in A)\wedge(x\in B)\wedge(y = f(x))\}\\\\
& = \{y\in Y \mid\exists x\,(x\in A)\wedge(y = f(x))\}\cap\{y\in Y \mid \exists x\,(x\in B)\wedge(y = f(x))\}\\\\
& = f(A)\cap f(B) \subset f(B)
\end{align*}

Am I on the right track? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In my opinion, it's unnecessary to use $\cap$. Instead,you could write {$f(x) \in Y| x \in A$} straightaway.

Comment: I would write $\{y\in Y\mid \exists x(x\in A\land y=f(x))\}$, since otherwise $x$ is a free variable. The suggestion above is also alright, eliminating the need of $y$ in the first place.

The argument is perhaps easier in words: if $w\in f(A)$, then $w=f(x)$ for some $x\in A$, so since $A\subset B$ we see $w=f(x)$ for some $x\in B$, therefore $w\in f(B)$.

Comment: As others have said, I think this question is more straightforward. That being said, your proof looks perfectly correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

One flaw in your proof: The statement
$$
\{y\in Y \mid\exists x\,(x\in A)\wedge(x\in B)\wedge(y = f(x))\}\\
= \{y\in Y \mid\exists x\,(x\in A)\wedge(y = f(x))\}\cap\{y\in Y \mid \exists x\,(x\in B)\wedge(y = f(x))\}
$$
is incorrect. There is only set inclusion ($\subset$) between the left and right sides, not equality. Fortunately your proof goes through with this correction.

The bulk of your argument amounts to a proof that
$$
f(A\cap B)\subset f(A)\cap f(B),\tag a
$$
which is part (a) of the question that you've linked. Having proven (a), you can apply it to shorten your argument for (b):

> If $A\subset B$, then $A=A\cap B$ so $f(A)=f(A\cap B)\subset f(A)\cap f(B)\subset f(B)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you give a counter-example?

Comment: @eagertolearn Let $f(x)=x^2$, $A=\{-1\}$, $B=\{1\}$. Then $f(A)=f(B)=\{1\}$ but $A\cap B$ is empty.

Comment: Interesting. The book which I am studying asks first to prove that
$$A\subset B \Longrightarrow f(A)\subset f(B)$$
before proving that
$$f(A\cap B) \subset f(A)\cap f(B)$$

Comment: @eagertolearn In fact the two statements are equivalent: you can use one to prove the other.

Comment: Based on such equivalence, could you provide a different proof from the link above?

Comment: @eagertolearn Yes, note the comment "By the way, (a) is a consequence of (b)." Here is the proof: Since $A\cap B\subset A$, we know $f(A\cap B)\subset f(A)$. Similarly $A\cap B\subset B$, so $f(A\cap B)\subset f(B)$.

Comment: Just one observation: at your example, $A\not\subset B$. Does this affect your argument?

Comment: The counterexample shows that for arbitrary $A$ and $B$, equality does not hold in (a). If you know that $A\subset B$, then yes equality holds in that special case.

Comment: Therefore, since $A\subset B$ by hypothesis, one may claim that $f(A) = f(A)\cap f(B)$, right?

Comment: If you make that claim, then you are assuming the validity of (b), i.e. that if $A\subset B$ then $f(A)\subset f(B)$. I am not sure where you are going with this line of reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

If y in f(A), then exists a in A with y = f(a).
Thus exists a in B with y = f(x);  y in f(A).