# I have two questions about the proof $A \subseteq B \implies f(A) \subseteq f(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Suppose we have a function $f: X \to Y$ where $A, B \subseteq X$

Prove that $A \subseteq B \implies f(A) \subseteq f(B)$

suppose that $a' \in f(A)$

$\implies \exists a \in A : f(a) = a'$ <--- does $f$ have to be surjective for this to be true? I've seen other posts covering this proof and they don't mention $f$ being surjective. For example, [$A$ subset $B$ implies $f(A)$ subset $f(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183793/a-subset-b-implies-fa-subset-fb) doesn't mention surjectivity

suppose $A \subseteq B$

$\implies a \in B$

$\implies f(a) \in f(B)$ <--- why is this true? How do we know that this image is not true: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec7HP.jpg ?

$\implies a' \in f(B)$

$\implies f(A) \subseteq f(B) \blacksquare$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. By definition, the assertion $a'\in f(A)$ *means* that there is some $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=a'$. So, the answer is: no, $f$ doesn't have to be surjective.
2. Because $f(B)$ is the set of those elements of $Y$ which are of the form $f(b)$, for some $b\in B$. But $a\in B$. Therefore, $f(a)\in f(B)$.

Comment: Ok. That clears things up for me for the second question. For the first question, I think I also see it. We're assuming that a' is itself an image, which implies that it must have come from some pre-image. a' not just some arbitrary element of Y, it's an image element of f(A)

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I think point 2. is too verbose. By point 1, $a'\in f(B)$ means that there is some $a$ in $B$ such that $f(a)=a'$, but this is precisely the case.